# UIWebView not respecting setContentOffset

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview

I am having an odd problem with my web view. The navigation bar is set to translucent, and when the window first loads, the top of the web view is underneath the nav bar; however, as soon as the user begins to scroll, the scrollbar shows up in the correct place. **Question: how would I go about making the web view display the top of the page (in this case a PDF) under the navigation bar?**

Note: adding the following method does not fix the problem:

```
func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView: UIWebView) {
    webView.scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: 200), animated: true);
}
```

[image: scroll view is inset correctly]
[image: wrong content inset]

Left: scroll view is properly inset when the user begins to scroll

Right: when the window loads, the WebView shows under the navigation bar.

I am attempting to achieve a translucent navigation bar with the following layout from interface builder (Note: web view is set to auto layout top=0, left=-16, right=-16, bottom=0:

[image: configuration from interface builder]